# Convert object a JSON object to string

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to convert a json object to a string using but I'm getting 'No Value for NAMES'. My code is as follows:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp);
 String c = jsonObject.getString("NAME");
 msg("" + c);
```

Currently my object is as follows:

`{"Names":[{"NAME":"Haircut"},{"NAME":"Blowdry"},{"NAME":"styling "},{"NAME":"treatment "},{"NAME":"braiding"}]}`

How can I convert this data so that I may ingest the data into a listview dynamically.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Names isn't an object, it's an array. Try getJsonArray("Names") and then iterate over it (for loop, etc.) and add its data to a List<String>. Don't have time to post example code but maybe someone else can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names is and array in your JSON. So, firstly your should get it. Try this one:

```
JSONArray names = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("Names");
((JSONObject) names.get(0)).get("NAME");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help big time. It now works.You've really brighten up my day

Comment: @Clarence If this solution worked for you mark it as the answer